# Multi Threading with datastax java driver 2.0

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

My Data Model is based on time series(inserts feeds from various sources in cassandra CFs.) Can anyone suggest how to do inserts in Multi Threading.? Is executing query with executeAsync method similar to multi threading ? Is there any property of cassandra.yaml which I need to set to achieve Multi Threading ? Or any other prerequisites.

Answer (score 4):

The driver is safe for multi-threaded use. What you will typically do is build your `Cluster` and get a `Session` instance during application startup, and then share the `Session` among all threads.

How you handle multi-threading is specific to your code. I don't know SQS either, but I imagine you'd either have multiple consumers that poll from the queue and process the messages themselves, or maybe dispatch the messages to a pool of workers.

Regarding `executeAsync`, the returned `ResultSetFuture` implements Guava's `ListenableFuture`, so you can register a success callback with `addListener`. But you'll have to provide an `Executor` to run that callback on (I don't recommend `MoreExecutors#sameThreadExecutor` as mentioned in the Javadoc, because your callback would end up running on one of the driver's I/O threads).

As mentioned by Carlo, a simple approach is to use the synchronous `execute`, and have your worker block until it gets a response from Cassandra, and then acknowledge the message.

Answer (score 2):

`executeAsync()` creates a separate thread for the execution of the statement and immediately returns the control to caller -- a `Future<ResultSet>` will have your result. When working with this approach you won't know if any exception occurred until you're inside the `Future`.

In Cassandra you don't have to set anything. Just keep under control the thread-number within your application and initialize properly the Java Driver providing a [PoolingOptions](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html) object that match your needs.

HTH, Carlo

Comment: Thanks for Response, in my process I'm receiving multiple messages from AWS SQS  and preparing Insert Statement then execute it and then delete messages from SQS. As SQS has  messageReceiptHandler which enable use to identify the message but now in the case of Future<ResultSet>, how can we identify the acknowledgements ?

Comment: Don't know SQS and I'm not sure I understood all but a solution could be to avoid executeAsync() and implement your own Callable<Message> (or whatever you need, a message handler etc.), within the call() method you perform your query and then return the Message so you can perform what you need (or in alternative implement a Runnable and you perform all in your run())

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing the query in multithreading environment, then make sure you wait for the executeAsync(statement) to complete,
session.executeAsync(statement) will return immediately, it does not guarantee whether the query is valid or submitted successfully. So if you're using threadpool then always use

```
ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync(statement);
future.getUninterruptibly();
```

This will wait for the query to be submitted and will not consume memory.